# Error when using CFileDialog to open file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, cfiledialog

I got an error:

```
error C2664: 'CFileDialog::CFileDialog(BOOL,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,DWORD,LPCTSTR,CWnd *,DWORD,BOOL)' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'const char [52]' to 'LPCTSTR'
```

in the following code:

```
CFileDialog dlgFile(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, "Movie Files (*.avi;*.mpg;*.mp4)|*.avi;*.mpg;*.mp4||", this);
```

Please help me.
this code worked fine in one project, but when I copy it to other project, it shows the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect one project is built as UNICODE and the other is ANSI or MBCS.

Try using the `_TEXT()` macro, like this:

```
CFileDialog dlgFile(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, 
    _T("Movie Files (*.avi;*.mpg;*.mp4)|*.avi;*.mpg;*.mp4||"), this);
```